# scala map method can not correctly resolve function type in collection with fixed function types

Tags: scala

I have the following code,

```
def obsKPI[T](kpi: Option[T], f: T => Unit) = {
    kpi match {
        case Some(obsValue) => f(obsValue) 
        case _ => Unit
    }
}

def func1(str:String):Unit = println(str)
def func2(num: Int):Unit = println(num)

//option1: val inputArgs = List((Some("first"),(func1 _)),(Some("third"), (func1 _)))
//option2: val inputArgs = List((Some(456), (func2 _)),(None,(func2 _)))
// option3: 
val inputArgs = List((Some("first"),(func1 _)),(Some(456), (func2 _)),(Some("third"), (func1 _)),(None,(func2 _)))

inputArgs.map(x => obsKPI(x._1, x._2))
```

when running either option 1 or 2 (the inputArgs list contains function of only String=>Unit or Int=>Unit), the code works, but when running option 3, I get an error:

```
:68: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int with String => Unit
 required: Any => Unit
              inputArgs.map(x => obsKPI(x._1, x._2))
                                                ^
```

Thanks for letting me know what went wrong in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions aren't covariant in their parameter types (they are in fact contravariant). 
This means, that if `Foo` is a subclass of `Bar`, `Foo => Unit` is *not* a subclass of `Bar => Unit` (the opposite is true).

In your case, you are trying to coerce `func1` and `func2` to `Any => Unit`, but that cannot work, because their types are incompatible - one is `String => Unit`, and the other one is `Int => Unit`.

One way to get around this problem, is to use a case class rather than a tuple:

```
 case class KPI[T](t: Option[T], f: T => Unit)
 def obsKPI(kpi: KPI[_]) = kpi match {
    case KPI(Some(k), f) => f(k) 
    case _ => () // `()` is the value of type Unit. Unit, as you had it is the value of type Unit.type - not what you want at all
 }
 // You can also write the above more concise like this: def obsKPI[T](kpi: KPI[T]) = kpi.t.foreach(kpi.f)

 def func1(str:String) = println(str)
 def func2(num: Int) = println(num)

 val inputArgs = List(KPI(Some("first"),func1 _), KPI(Some(456), func2 _), KPI(Some("third"), func1 _), KPI[Int](None,func2 _))

 inputArgs.foreach(obsKPI) // Could do .map here too, but ending up with a list of ()s is unlikely what you you want.
```

You can make it look a bit more elegant, if you make your `obsKPI` into a member of the case class:

```
case class KPI[T](t: Option[T], f: T => Unit) {
  def obs = t.foreach(f)
}
val inputArgs = List(KPI(Some("first"),func1 _), KPI(Some(456), func2 _), KPI(Some("third"), func1 _), KPI[Int](None,func2 _))

inputArgs.foreach(_.obs)
```

Comment: According to the source code "final abstract class Int private extends AnyVal ". AnyVal is again extention of Any. Atleast tis should be working right if i comment out def func1(str:String)  ?

Comment: `Int` is a subclass of `Any`, yes. But `Int => Unit` is _not_ a subclass of `Any => Unit`
If you remove `func1`, and only leave `func2` everywhere, that will work, because `inputArgs` will be a `List[Int, Int=>Unit]`, so the `T` in `obsKPI` call will resolve to `Int` rather than `Any`

Comment: Thank you very much! and thank you for correcting my other mistakes in the code!